# How to add Leading Zeroes and Decimal Points at the same time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried many combinations of the SQL functions; so as to have a 12 digit number including the dot character, including leading zeroes and decimal points.

For example:

for the number **121.22**, I want to format it to **000000121.22**

or for the number **12.2**, I want to format it to **000000012.20**

or for the number **100**, I want to format it to **000000100.00**

I have used the following function; but I lost the decimal points if it's zero.

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000000000'+ STR(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MYNUMBER),12,2),12);
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem in Microsoft SQL?

Comment: So, mySQL, Oracle or SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use the format() function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(121.22, '000000000000.00')
SELECT FORMAT(12.2, '000000000000.00')
```

---

000000000121.22

---

000000000012.20

Answer (score 1):

for `ms sql versions not in (2012,2014)`:

```
cast(right('000000000',9-len(floor(the_number))) as varchar) 
+ cast( cast(the_number as decimal(10,2))as varchar)
```

for `ms sql versions in (2012,2014)`:

```
 format(the_number ,'000000000000.00')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT padded_id = REPLACE(STR(id, 12), SPACE(1), '0')
```

Is what I add to use (In SQL server) leading 0's as needed, change the 12 to whatever total number of digits you want it to be.

This allows for non hard coded values, just make sure id or whatever column/param you want to format is set.